# Child table not taking full width of parent table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a nested table which should take up the entire width of the cell in which it is expanding. Currently, it is leaving some margins which I have tried to reduce but what I did is not working. I have tried other solutions previously answered to similar questions but nothing is working.

```js
$(function(){
    $(".fold-table tr.view").on("click", function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("open").next(".fold").toggleClass("open");
    });
  });
```

```css
.table{
  font-size:12px;
  width: 50%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 2px; 
}
table thead th{ 
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

table td,th{
  border-top: 0px;
}
th{
  background-color:#FFFF
}
.main tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #F8F8F8
 }

 .tbody tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color:#F8F8F8
}
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view td, table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view th {
  cursor: pointer;
}
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view.open {
  background:  #ddd;
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold {
  display: none;
}
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold.open {
  display: table-row;
}
.span{
  width: 100% !important;
}
.fold-content > table { 
  width: 100%;
}
table.fold-content > tr{
  background-color:#ddd !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
<table class="table fold-table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Contact Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="view main">

      <td >John</td>
      <td >j@g.com</td>
      <td >35373726</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold">
      <td colspan="3 span">
        <div class="fold-content">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="view">
                <td >John</td>
                <td >j@g.com</td>
                <td >35373726</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="view">
               <td >John</td>
               <td >j@g.com</td>
               <td >35373726</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="view">
                <td >John</td>
                <td >j@g.com</td>
                <td >35373726</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >John</td>
      <td >j@g.com</td>
      <td >35373726</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >John</td>
      <td >j@g.com</td>
      <td >35373726</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >John</td>
      <td >j@g.com</td>
      <td >35373726</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="table.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Please suggest how I can deal with this scenario.

Thanks as always !

Comment: Are you saying the nested table is leaving margins ? Are you able to screenshot it and paste it with current and desired output ? padding: 0.75em is by default. if thats what you are taking about!

Comment: add a css for solve this 'width issue' tr.fold.open > td {  padding: 0; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following rule (verbose as it is) solved the problem.

```css
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold.open > td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

When inspecting that `td`, you can see the padding applied to it (`.75rem`, or `12px` of space on the left and right of the element).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this actually. But it only removes the padding from left side. Even adding padding-right:0 does nothing.

Comment: @HarshVardhanBandta I'm looking at it in the editor right now and there is no right padding at all.

Comment: Ah ! it is solved now. It was receiving width from the parent element ! I changed that. It is fixed now. Thanks :D

Comment: If Andy's answer solved your issue, why don't you accept it as a correct answer?

Comment: @HarshVardhanBandta I would appreciate it if you would accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to `.table td` having a `.75rem` padding which when nested gives the child table an additional `.75rem` padding.

You could reduce the inner table's td padding to zero like this

```
<tr class="fold">
      <td style="padding: 0" colspan="3 span">
        <div class="fold-content">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="view">
                <td >John</td>
                <td >j@g.com</td>
                <td >35373726</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="view">
               <td >John</td>
               <td >j@g.com</td>
               <td >35373726</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="view">
                <td >John</td>
                <td >j@g.com</td>
                <td >35373726</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```